# How to pause output in Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows-terminal

I use the new, open source [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal) and it's really a much nicer way of working as the old legacy console. Still, I cannot pause the output of a running program. The old console supports Ctrl-S/Ctrl-Q to stop/resume output, or I can mark something with the mouse. Both pause the output and even the running program. Also, Scroll-Lock has no effect.

Is there anything like this for Windows Terminal?

Comment: The "pause" key on the keyboard seems to work, at least for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tomasz86 points out in the comments, newer versions of Windows Terminal (I have 1.14.1451) support the `Pause` key to stop scrolling.

Comment: Just for the record, as my comment was "chosen" as the answer , the inability to pause on mouse click is actually the reason why I don't use Windows Terminal myself. I find the classic mouse click quicker, and also there are many cases where the `Pause` key isn't available at all (e.g. some laptops) or easily accessible (e.g. touch screens).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Windows Terminal does not have an option that allows you to pause output. An [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/980) was filed for this feature about two years ago but it has only been partially implemented - Scrolling now freezes on select, but the output still continues.